# Insert on duplicate key update with laravel 5.1 eloquent (only one query)

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I want to perform insert on duplicate key update with eloquent model without making two queries, the problem is when I use `updateOrCreate()` it does two queries

```
 /**
 * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with     values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return static
 */
public static function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    $instance = static::firstOrNew($attributes);
    //second query
    $instance->fill($values)->save();

    return $instance;
}
public static function firstOrNew(array $attributes)
{
    //first query
    if (! is_null($instance = (new static)->newQueryWithoutScopes()->where($attributes)->first())) {
        return $instance;
    }

    return new static($attributes);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It not running two queries, it uses the same object to update or insert. and one thing more, this is doing by Laravel, so this is already optimized way

Comment: you can do something custom on your own model by using raw query like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: thanks @MM2  that's what i did i made my own query using DB::statement()